# How write a script that works on modal popup & on full page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following view which is forced to be displayed as a modal popup using jQuery :-

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" /> |  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<span id="progress" class="text-center" style="display: none;">
                <img src="~/img/ajax-loaders/ajax-loader-5.gif" alt="wait" />
                Wait..
            </span>
```

and i wrote the following script, which will fires if the user click on Create/Edit/Delete links . where the script will show a progree message + disable the submit button:-

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {

        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
            $('#myModal').modal({
                height: 1000,
                width: 1200,
                resizable: true,
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');
            $('#myModalContent').removeData("validator");
            $('#myModalContent').removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#myModalContent');
            bindForm(this);
        });
        return false;
    });


});
    function bindForm(dialog) {
        $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
            $('.btn btn-default').prop("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#progress').show();
            if ($(this).valid()) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
```

but let say the that the user instead of clicking on the link, he chose to "Open link in new browser" , so the view will render insdie the browser (not as modal popup) and the script will not fire, so when the user click on submit button,, the submit button will not be disabled + the progress will not be shown?
So can anyone adivce where i need to place a script that always works ?

Comment: Do you want to retain the ability to launch in a new tab or window?

Comment: @Press  yes since some users will prefer to be adding data inside  a full page not a popup..